# How to read Arabic text from varchar column?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have sqlite database who store Arabic text in `varchar` field 
I used this code,but when try to read the value question mark is appear instead character

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Quran.sqlite;Version=3;");
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Qtxt FROM tblQTxt'", con);
con.Open();
SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

dr.Read();
textBox1.Text = dr["Qtxt"].ToString();

dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

I used "DB Browser for SQLite" fro opening database
when try to view field as binary mode and then export as text I will see the true character

[image: DB Browser for SQLite]

how can read this filed truly?

Comment: SQLite itself does not change strings; this might be a DB Browser bug. Do other tools like SQLite Manager work?

Comment: @CL. in this database string saved as binary and must be converted to text

Comment: @CL. this link for download database : https://ufile.io/qa4ts

Comment: What do you mean with "saved as binary"? Show the code!

Comment: @CL. as you see in a image in right side panel view this field as binary mode and when i export as a text file the char is truly viewed.

Comment: Obviously it's a wrong encoding. And nobody knows which one your code and your data are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Quran.sqlite;Version=3;");
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Qtxt2 FROM tblQTxt where Sore='1' and Aye='1'", con);

    SQLiteDataAdapter dAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
    dAdapter.Fill(dSet);

    if (dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {

        Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
        data = (Byte[])(dSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Qtxt2"]);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        ms.Position = 0;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms,Encoding.GetEncoding(1256));
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = text;

    }
```